# Geos ruby - Create point

Tags: ruby, geometry, geos

I'm struggling using the GEOS library for Ruby, I just want to create a simple point with IRB.
`require geos` return true so the install works. But the I don't really understand the [documentation](https://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1geom_1_1Point.html) and nothing helps on the [github](https://github.com/dark-panda/geos-extensions) page.

I tried `Geos::Point.new('POINT(0 0)')` but it returns a `TypeError: allocator undefined for Geos::Point`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) is a C++ library. It doesn't help much to look at the documentation there to learn the required Ruby syntax.

You'd need this [`rgeo`](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo) gem.

Here's a good tutorial : ["Geo-Rails Part 3: Spatial Data Types with RGeo"](http://daniel-azuma.com/articles/georails/part-3)

As an example :

```
# gem install rgeo
require 'rgeo'

factory = RGeo::Cartesian.factory

point = factory.point(0, 0)
puts point
# POINT (0.0 0.0)

square = factory.parse_wkt("POLYGON((1 0, 0 1, -1 0, 0 -1, 1 0))")
puts square
# POLYGON ((1.0 0.0, 0.0 1.0, -1.0 0.0, 0.0 -1.0, 1.0 0.0))

puts square.contains?(point)
# true
```